# Changing date format javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pulling some data from two different APIs and I want to the objects later on.

However, I'm getting two different date formats: this format "1427457730" and this format "2015-04-10T09:12:22Z". How can I change the format of one of these so I have the same format to work with?

```
$.each(object, function(index) {
  date = object[index].updated_at;
}
```

Comment: Load [`es5-shim`](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) to ensure that the environment handles [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) then `date = (/^\d+$/).test(d) ? new Date(d * 1000).toISOString().slice(0, -5) + 'Z': d;` where `d` is `object[index].updated_at` Now all formats will be like `"2015-04-10T09:12:22Z"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want in javascript, are date objects.
The first string is seconds since epoch, javascript needs milliseconds, so multiply it by 1000;
The second string is a valid ISO date, so if the string contains a hyphen just pass it into `new Date`.

```
var date = returned_date.indexOf('-') !== -1 ? returned_date : returned_date * 1000;

var date_object = new Date(date);
```

Making both types into date objects, you could even turn that into a handy function

```
function format_date(date) {
    return new Date(date.indexOf('-') !== -1 ? date : date * 1000);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/fg9fvqt6/)

Comment: This is also a great way of solving it. what would be easier to work with, this way? or the method of @robertklep? In the future I would like to order objects chronological based on these dates

Comment: What's easier depends on you I suppose, this takes both types, and returns objects, which you then could stick in an array, and just sort them

Comment: I tried to sort it today, but it won't sort. I'm using .sort(); on the array. I sorts nicely if I fill the array with something else like strings. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1207224/Screen%20Shot%202016-01-10%20at%2013.20.36.png any suggestions on sorting with the function you wrote?

Comment: @user3199999 - sorting dates should work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/fg9fvqt6/1/

Comment: thanks man, I first tried it without the function in the sort. thanks for the tip. I'm not a expert in adding those minimalistic functions, with the sort of function you made for sorting. Now A and B are a item in the array. I my case I'm using a array filled with arrays which have a timestamp on the first place like so -> https://jsfiddle.net/fg9fvqt6/2/

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option:

```
var timestamp  = 1427457730;
var date       = new Date(timestamp * 1000); // wants milliseconds, not seconds
var dateString = date.toISOString().replace(/\.\d+Z/, 'Z'); // remove the ms
```

`dateString` will now be `2015-03-27T12:02:10Z`.

Comment: This worked for me. if got the same formatting perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
var timestamp = 1427457730;
var date      = '2015-04-10T09:12:22Z';

var m1 = moment(timestamp);
var m2 = moment(date);

console.log(m1);
console.log(m2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can use `.format()` method in moment to parse the date to whatever format you want, just like:

```
m2.format('YYYY MMM DD ddd HH:mm:ss') // 2015 Apr 10 Fri 17:12:22
```

Check out the docs for [more format tokens](http://momentjs.com/docs/#year-month-and-day-tokens).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://momentjs.com/. It is THE date/time formatting library for JavaScript - very simple to use, extremely flexible.

Comment: thanks for the tip, though if possible I would like to not use additional plugins since this is the only date/time stuff I'm working with