# Change date string to another date format in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date-format

How can I change a date string to another date format in angularjs?
Lets say I get from DB a string in this format: "**31/01/2015 2:21 PM**".
I need to change it to "**31-Jan-2015 14:21**".
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing date format javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695685/changing-date-format-javascript)

Comment: (Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript may be more canonical.  There are literally hundreds of near-identical questions on this subject.)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming perhaps incorrectly that you want to display your date..
You can use the html time element:

```
<time [attr.datetime]="Post.PublishDate">
    {{Post.PublishDate | date: 'longDate' }}
</time>
```

Edit: per question substitute 'longDate' with your format string i.e. 'dd-MMM-yyyy'.